# automation of tasks

Tags: dll, automation, exe

which scripting language/tool is best for automating a task?

I have an exe for which I don't know any of the list of functions used. if I know any of the functions used, then I thought I can try using those functions by referencing the exe/dll to VB or any other scripting language. I know that the exe is developed from Delphi.

Is there any way that I can automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is here; what are you trying to automate exactly?  Are you trying to call functions provided by a DLL, or are you trying to find out what functionality is actually exposed *from* the DLL.  I'm not even sure you have a DLL, you mention a .exe most of the time...

Please refer to the guidelines and try to state your question more clearly, if I'm alone in not understanding your question then I'm sorry and I hope another more helpful SOer comes to your rescue!

EDIT:  After helpful comments from OP, this question is, I believe, '**how can I automate interaction with a GUI?**'

If this is a Windows GUI, then I would recommend using Python and the [pyWinAuto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) package.  This will allow you to accomplish quite a good range of basic to intermediate manipulation of a Windows GUI application.  If that's not up your street, then [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818907/automate-interaction-with-a-gui-interface) has numerous other suggestions.

HTH

Comment: I don't have a dll. I have only one exe. The exe opens a GUI window. I need to update some text in the GUI.